# AWS ElasticSearchService index_create_block_exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a new index in AWS ElasticSearch cluster after increasing the cluster size and seeing index_create_block_exception. How can i rectify this? I tried searching but did not get exact answers. Thank you.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://<aws_es_endpoint>/optimus/'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_create_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/10/cluster create-index blocked (api)];"}],"type":"index_create_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/10/cluster create-index blocked (api)];"},"status":403}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html?id=d0e9728), the above exception is being thrown due to a low memory in disks.

> For t2 instances, when the JVMMemoryPressure metric exceeds 92%,
>   Amazon ES triggers a protection mechanism by blocking all write
>   operations to prevent the cluster from getting into red status. When
>   the protection is on, write operations will fail with a
>   ClusterBlockException error, new indexes cannot be created, and the
>   IndexCreateBlockException error will be thrown.

I'm afraid the [issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=736137) is still on.

Comment: Issue existed with the service. Now resolved by their team. Thank you for your response.

Comment: same protection mechanisms happen on on c4 instances.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, index creation can be unblocked using:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://<end-point>:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"persistent": {"cluster.blocks.create_index": false}}'
```

Make sure to replace `<end-point>` with your Elasticsearch end-point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get this error if you run out of disk space.

This should of course not happen after *increasing* the cluster size, but if you suddenly get this error it'd be worth to check that *all* your instances has storage left - i.e. don't look at the *Total free storage space* graph but at the *Minimum free storage space* one.