# index_create_block_exception - ElasticSearch (Not an AWS Service)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, fluent-bit

I have installed ElasticSearch basic (7.7.1) on a single AWS EC2 instance node (t3.medium).

While running Fluent-bit in docker, getting the

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_create_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/10/cluster create-index blocked (api)];"}],"type":"index_create_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/10/cluster create-index blocked (api)];"},"status":403}"`

I am not using ElasticSearch service provided by AWS, so this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736462/aws-elasticsearchservice-index-create-block-exception/76627047#76627047) is no help.

[es config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNRbl.png)

Additional info: FluentD (td-agent) running on other servers have no issue in creating the index.

I can add the fluentbit config too if needed. Thanks in advance.

I tried to get logs streaming from a server to Elasticsearch, but getting error thrown.

Comment: Can you share the elasticsearch logs and fluentbit config?